# H is normal in K iff K is a subgroup of the normalizer of H - is this false?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I think I found a mistake in my book.. It says that if $G$ is a group and we define the normalizer of $U\in P(G)$ as $N_G(U) = \{ g\in G \mid gU = Ug\}$, then if $H,K\leq G$, we have:
$$ H \unlhd K  \Leftrightarrow K\leq N_G(H)$$ .

The $\Rightarrow$ part of the implication is true and I was able to prove it. However, the reverse does guarantee that $H$ is normal in $K$ **only** if we can somehow prove that $H$ is actually a subgroup of $K$. I actually believe there is a counterexample without the addition of $H$ being a subset of $K$.

**NOTE:**  The book actually has an inverted subgroup sign for the right hand side of the equivalene, but I found out it should definitely be the other way around. They even say $N_G(H)$ is the *smallest* subgroup of $G$ containing $H$ as a normal subgroup, but I found this to also be false (it's actually the largest).. they seem to have messed up the ordering.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: Off the top of my head, shouldn't the condition just be that $K$ is a subgroup of the normalizer of $H$? The identifier $U$ has no meaning in your displayed formula.

Comment: Yes, it was H, I am sorry :(

Comment: The book is a Romanian old book: "Bazele Algebrei" (translates as Fundamentals of Algebra), by C. Nita, C. Nastasescu, C. Vraciu.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure your counterexample is right. Consider any element $g$ of the group which normalizes $H$, but $g \not\in H$. Then $\langle g\rangle$, the subgroup generated by $g$, is a subgroup of $N_G(H)$, but we likely do not have $H \subseteq\langle g\rangle$.

To be more concrete, you could consider the alternating group $A_n$. Let $\tau$ be any transposition. Then we have $\langle\tau\rangle \leq N_{S_n}(A_n) = S_n$, but we certainly do not have $A_n \leq \langle\tau\rangle$.

(Or cyclic groups of the dihedral group could give you a similar counterexample.)

The authors were probably thinking of the LHS of your displayed equation as simply the "normalizing" property, without the subset property.